# Windows ACL deny move of folders on a hierarchy level

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, windows-server, acl

I have the goal to prevent Users from accidentally move or delete folders on one specific hierarchy level of an Windows Server 2019 Share.

## Example:

Two User Groups: `Admin` and `User`

```
|-RootShareDirecory      <= Directory that is Shared
  |- ProjectFolder1      <= Folder should only be moved / changed / deleted by an admin
     |- File1.doc        <= User has full access to the content it self.
     |- SubFolder2       <= User has full access to the content it self.
  |- ProjectFolder2      <= Folder should only be moved / changed / deleted by an admin
  ...
```

## What have I tried:

I have found multiple solutions for this Issue online, eg:

1. [How to prevent users from deleting one folder, while still giving them modify permissions to other files and folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/1036010/how-to-prevent-users-from-deleting-one-folder-while-still-giving-them-modify-pe/1036070#1036070)
2. https://blogs.uw.edu/curreri/disable-click-and-drag-on-folders/
3. https://dilrukj.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/prevent-users-deleting-moving-or-drag-and-drop-folders-in-a-file-share/

So I tried all of them, obviously with no success.

The most of the solutions rely on creating a acl for `ProjectFolderX` that deny the delete action to the `User`.

Unfortunately i can only get two different results:

1. The `ProjectFolderX` is still moveable, but every other action within the `RootShareDirecory` is denied.
2. The `ProjectFolderX` is not movable but also the direct  content within ( eg. `File1.doc` is not writable.

Can anyone give me a hint, how to solve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: I usually set permissions on "Traverse Directory" and "List Folders" for directories that shouldn't be changed by users, have you already tried ?

Comment: Try https://superuser.com/questions/1367481/prevent-folder-from-being-deleted-moved-renamed-in-windows/1367485

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You @harrymc for the useful Link.
Here is the solution how i have solved this issue now.

I'm describing the permissions for the `user`. Use the Advanced Security dialog to add this permissions. ( Right click / Settings / Security / Advanced )

## RootShareDirecory

- Permission for `This Folder, SubFolder and Files` only `Read, Execute`

## ProjectFolderX

- Activate Permission inheritance.
- Permission for `This Folder` every permission **excluding** `Delete`.
- Permission for `Only Subfolder and Files` Full Access.

## Explaination

In order to prevent a file from beeing moved, you have to disable the Delete. Unfortunately there are two values which influence if an folder can be deleted:

1. The `Delete` Permission on the folder it self
2. The `Delete subfolders and files` of the **parent** Folder.

Please ensure the user which is not allowed to delete, has none of these two permissions.